# Serve MEDIA_URL a view in urlpatterns

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a view for MEDIA_URL and insert the url into urlpatterns.
(to catch query to MEDIA_URL and make some actions inside view method for MEDIA_URL)
I have MEDIA_URL with link to amazon S3 resource.
How to make urlpattern to invoke my view, where the url is external link, but is MEDIA_URL of my project?

I've tried to insert just media/ url, but this doesn't get invoked:

```
url(r'^media/', media_view),
```

surely because it is not original website that I'm serving with django app.

```
urlpatterns = [
              url(r'^$', home_view),
]
```

Comment: This isn't clear. If MEDIA_URL points to S3, you don't need to serve it.

Comment: I mean, I want to catch request to MEDIA_URL and make some actions inside view method. Is it possible?